# How to find limsup and liminf for sequence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Given $A_n$ $=$ {$w$$|$$0$ $\le$$w$$\le$$1$$-$$\frac{1}{n}$}
Find

$\limsup_{n \to \infty}$$A_n$ $\text{and}$ $\liminf_{n \to \infty}$$A_n$.

Can anyone guide me on how to solve this question?

I know that $\liminf_{n \to \infty}$$A_n$$=$$$
\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\ge N} A_n$$
and

$\limsup_{n \to \infty}$$A_n$$=$ $$
\bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n
$$

$A_1$$=$${0}$

$A_2$$=$$[$$0$,$\frac{1}{2}$$]$

$A_3$$=$$[$$0$,$\frac{2}{3}$$]$

$A_4$$=$$[$$0$,$\frac{3}{4}$$]$
and when n goes to infinity, $A_n$ is approaching 1.

is 
$\liminf_{n \to \infty}$$A_n$ equals to the union of all the intersection of $A_m$ from m equal to n till infinity? which means I will get [0,1)?
Please correct me, thanks.

Comment: How is limsup even defined for sets? I only know the definition for real numbers...

Comment: @5xum as far as I understand really $\limsup$ is two operations combined, i.e. you take $\sup$ of some set (which depends on $n$) and then take the limit of the values you get as $n \to \infty$. In this sense the $\limsup$ of sets is entirely well defined and for sequences you just take the sets to be $\{a_k \mid k \ge n\}$

Comment: The definitions include the inner expressions $\bigcap_{n\ge N} A_n$ and $\bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n$. Can you evaluate these for general $N$? (You haven't defined $C_n$, but it seems related to the first expression.) Once you do so, you should be able to complete your calculations. (By the way, limsup and liminf of a nested sequence of sets turns out to be pretty simple....)

Comment: @DanZimm You say "take the limit of the values", but in order to have a limit, you need a distance measure. What is the limit of a sequence of sets?

Comment: @5xum of course in order to do this you need to be working in some sort of ordered metric space, it seems pretty clear here that were working in $\mathbb{R}$. Nonetheless in general just having an ordered space induces a topological space in which you can take the limit - in this way you don't need metrizability.

Comment: @5xum I'm going to leave my comments up for reference of others, but relooking at his post it appears he's looking to do something different (he defined the limsup and liminf he's using) than what I was talking about - apologies for any frustration I may have caused. Also, I was saying that once you take the inf of a set it is then a value in your general space, thus the sequence is in your general space (not in the power set of your space).

Comment: @DanZimm You have a topological space on the set of real NUMBERS, but in order to have a limsup of a sequence of sets, you need a topology on the set of all subsets of the reals. So no, you cannot speak of limits of a sequence of sets just because you have a metric defined on the universal set. You still need a metric (or at least a topology) on the sets themselves.

Comment: @5xum you're skipping entirely over how I was explaining how one can interpret the $\limsup$ of a sequence of sets; to reiterate, look at the sequence of $s_n = \sup A_n$ and see what it converges to

Comment: @GregMartin I edited the question, the previous $C_n$ supposed to be $A_n$, what should I do after I figure out the sets?

Comment: You are right that $[0,1)$ is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim \inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n\ge N} A_n$ can also be interpreted as follows: this is the set of $x$ such that $x$ is eventually in every $A_n$ (if the left $N$ is that $x$ is in the union of the intersections of all $A_n$ with $n \ge N$, this defines this tail (eventually = all but finitely many)).

Also $\lim \sup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n\ge N} A_n$ can be seen as all $x$ such that $x$ is in infinitely many $A_n$ (i.e. the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: x \in A_n \}$ is infinite). This makes it clear that the lim inf is smaller than the limsup in general (being in almost all $A_n$ implies being in infinitely many of them).

Now look at your $A_n = \{x: 0 \le x \le 1-\frac{1}{n} \}$. Its clear that these sets are increasing for increasing $n$, so if a set is in one $A_n$, it will be in all later ones. So here the lim sup and lim inf will be equal to each other (being in infinitely many is equivalent to being in one, which is equivalent to being in almost all of them). And as every $x < 1$ will eventually be smaller than some $1 - \frac{1}{n}$, all of $[0,1)$ is in these coinciding limits, and no other points are even in one of them.